# How can I query Zenodo's related identifiers fields?

Tags: zenodo

The [Zenodo](https://zenodo.org/) open data repository offers a web-based query interface with a [sophisticated query language](https://help.zenodo.org/guides/search/). However, I can't get queries for related identifiers (e.g. a data set that supplements a GiHub repository) to return anything.

For example, for this [Unix history repository Zenodo data set](http://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.2525587), the queries for the corresponding GitHub repository 
([related_identifiers.identifier:"https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo"](https://zenodo.org/search?page=1&size=20&q=related_identifiers.identifier:%22https:%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fdspinellis%2Funix-history-repo%22&sort=title)) and the DOI of the publication that documents it 
([related_identifiers.identifier:"10.1007/s10664-016-9445-5"](https://zenodo.org/search?page=1&size=20&q=related_identifiers.identifier:%2210.1007%2Fs10664-016-9445-5%22&sort=title)) return no results. Even simpler queries, such as for data sets whose related identifiers is a DOI ([related_identifiers.scheme:doi](https://zenodo.org/search?page=1&size=20&q=related_identifiers.scheme:doi&sort=title)) or for data sets associated with a supplement relationship ([related_identifiers.relation:isSupplementTo](https://zenodo.org/search?page=1&size=20&q=related_identifiers.relation:isSupplementTo&sort=title)) fail to return any results. Other queries, such as for data sets with restricted access rights ([accessrights:restricted](https://zenodo.org/search?page=1&size=20&q=accessrights:restricted)) or those by a specific creator ([creators.orcid:0000-0003-4231-1897](https://zenodo.org/search?page=1&size=20&q=creators.orcid:0000-0003-4231-1897)) work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this [is a limitation of the current query interface](https://github.com/zenodo/zenodo/issues/1508).  The query language does not support queries for nested fields, such as the related identifiers.  The provided documentation was misleading and has been corrected through [this pull request](https://github.com/zenodo/zenodo-docs-user/pull/70). In addition, a Zenodo developer commented that the corresponding identifiers can be accessed through the `related.identifier` keyword, for example [related.identifier:"10.1109/TSE.2019.2892149"](https://zenodo.org/search?page=1&size=20&q=related.identifier:%2210.1109%2FTSE.2019.2892149%22).